# Problem with proof connected with Riemann integral

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

I have a problem with a proof which seems to be easy, but I don't have any idea how to prove in the opposite side (from the end to the beginning).

We know that $\{x_n\}$ has uniform distibution on $[0,1]$ when
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\dfrac1n \sum\limits_{j=1}^n f(x_j)=\int\limits_0^1 f(x) dx
$$
is fulfilled for every function $f$ which is continuous on $[0,1]$. I have to prove that above condition is equivalent to the condition
$$
\forall_{k\in \mathbb{N}} \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \dfrac1n \sum\limits_{j=1}^n x_j^k=\dfrac{1}{k+1}.
$$

**My attempt**

*Proof.*

($\Rightarrow$) Taking $f(x_j)=x_j^k$ we obtain
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \dfrac1n \sum\limits_{j=1}^n x_j^k=\int\limits_0^1x^k dx=\dfrac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}|_0^1 =\dfrac{1}{k+1} \forall_{k\in \mathbb{N}}.$$

($\Leftarrow$) **???**

Thanks for any ideas, because this side of the proof is kind of enigmatic for me.

Comment: The condition gives you $$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{j = 1}^{n} p(x_j) \to \int_0^1 p(x)\,dx$$ for all polynomials $p$. Recall Weierstraß.

Comment: Thanks. Have you got in mind this version of theorem? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem

Comment: Yes (the plain Weierstraß approximation theorem, no need for the more general versions).